# Puntero dentro de un entry (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa que básicamente al introducir una serie de numeros, te añada automáticamente un caracter. Mi pregunta es si hay algún tipo de puntero en los `Entry()` de Python ya que al introducir externamente el caracter, el puntero se queda en la misma posición de el último caracter introducido mediante el teclado.

El ejemplo:

En el `Entry()` coloco `22` y quiero que automaticamente introduzca el caracter `/`.

Al hacerlo, el puntero se queda delante del 22 en vez de delante de `/`

He probado a darle el "focus" a otro widget y darle de nuevo el "focus" al Entry()

¿Hay algún método que te permita manejar el puntero dentro de un `Entry()`?

Answer (score 1):

Para modificar mediante código la posición del cursor de inserción dentro del `Entry` (y con ello la marca visible del mismo) debes usar el método `tkinter.Entry.icursor` indicando el índice en el que quieres que se muestre, si es al final del texto simplemente usa la constante `tkinter.END`.

Un ejemplo simple:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x50")
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill='x')

def agregar_texto():
    entry.insert(tk.END, "Hola Stackoverflow ")
    entry.icursor(tk.END)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Agregar", command=agregar_texto)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Simplemente debes llamar al método `icursor` en el método dónde modifiques el contenido del `Entry` inmediatamente después de insertar el nuevo texto.